# Using Sed to replace an array

Tags: bash, sed

```
#!/bin/bash
path_initial_case="/home/frederickthegreat/Desktop/Working Airfoil OpenFoam/Airfoil2D/"
path_output="/home/frederickthegreat/Desktop/"
initialvarray=(51 0 0)
angles=(0 2 4 6)
numberofcases=${#angles[*]}
velocity=30
i=0
pi=3.14159

while [ $i -lt $numberofcases ]
  do
  currentcase=${angles[i]}
  echo "$currentcase case"
  rad=$(bc -l <<< "scale=5; ($currentcase * $pi) / 180")
  echo "$rad rad "
  xcomp=$(bc -l <<< "scale=5; c(($currentcase * $pi) / 180) * ($velocity)")
  echo "$xcomp x"
  ycomp=$(bc -l <<< "scale=5; s(($currentcase * $pi) / 180) * ($velocity)")
  echo "$ycomp y"
  finalvarray=($xcomp $ycomp 0)
  echo ${finalvarray[@]}
  mkdir "Angle $currentcase"
  mkdir "Angle $currentcase"/"system"
  cp -r "${path_initial_case}"/"system/"*  "${path_output}""Angle $currentcase"/"system"
  mkdir "Angle $currentcase"/"0"
  cp -r "${path_initial_case}"/"0/"* "${path_output}""Angle $currentcase"/"0"
  sed -i "s/${initialvarray}/${finalvarray}/g" "${path_output}""Angle $currentcase"/"0/U"
  mkdir "Angle $currentcase"/"constant"
  cp "${path_initial_case}"/"constant/"* "${path_output}""Angle $currentcase"/"constant"
  ln -s "$path_initial_case""constant/polyMesh" "${path_output}""Angle $currentcase"/"constant"
  ((i++))
  echo "$i i"
done
```

In this script the sed command is being used to replace an array in another document. The initial array is defined as `initialvarray`. The final array, `finalvarray`, for which it is replaced is calculated inside the loop. The issue is that only the first element of the array is being replaced in the document. I would like the initial array to be replaced entirely by the final array ex. the initial array is (0 0 0), the final one is (1 1 1), and the result in the document should be (1 1 1).

Comment: I do not understand. Why do you need an array? Can't you just `finalarray="(0 0 0)"`? Aren't these just strings? Please create a __minimal__ [MCVE] - most of you scritp seems unrelated to the problem. Tip: just `for ((i=0; i < numberofcases; i++)); do...done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, and you will understand the error of your code above:

```
array=(1 2 3)
echo $array
```

The output will be

```
1
```

and not

```
(1 2 3)
```

I suggest to change `initialvarray` and `finalvarray` from array to string as follows:

```
initialvarray="(51 0 0)"
...
finalvarray="($xcomp $ycomp 0)"
```

Comment: Yes i understand that to print the entire thing a echo $array[@] would be necessary. However, i have attempted this change and it has not solved the issue.

Comment: I edited my answer. This should work, if there are no other errors I didn't see.

Comment: Thanks that last suggestion about the initialvarray and finalvarray did the trick. What is the diffrence(why did it work)?

Comment: With sed, you need to change a string into another string. An array only contains the elements, but not the spaces and/or parentheses around these elements.